# Run functions in parallel c++

Tags: c++

I have a `class A`, it has 4 methods. I'm creating two instances `a,b`. What I need is to run both `a.function 1 to 4` and `b.function 1 to 4` at the same time in c++?

Comment: You need to use threads.

Comment: Threads, perhaps? `ta = std::thread(&A::function, &a); tb = std::thread(&A::function, &b); ta.join(); tb.join();`

Comment: Have you tried before asking this question?

Comment: Pay attention that the situation becomes very difficult if you have a data race, for example if both threads try to modify the same variable.

Answer (score 3):

It seem to me, what you are asking for is multi-threading. For C++ you may rely on native thread support or  libraries like boost,which is cross platform and is widely used in industry. High level languages like Java and C# have the functionality for multi threading in built ,which is much easier to do this.

You can implement this is with the future library (`#include <future>`).

If your functions are

```
int my_func(int param1, int param2, int param3); 
int my_second_func(int param1, int param2, int param3);
```

Then you can use future to run the functions `asynchronously` as follows:

```
std::future<int> f = std::async(std::launch::async, my_second_func, arg1, arg2, arg3);
int result1 = my_func(arg1, arg2, arg3);
int result2 = f.get();
```

Where the functions are evaluated in separate threads, asynchronously (in parallel).

Comment: I see . Thank You .

Comment: C+11 and above has lot of capabilities in-built that were earlier provided by boost libraries. You can check out the link: https://thispointer.com/c-11-multithreading-part-1-three-different-ways-to-create-threads/